# Issue launching MATLAB code from JAVA

Tags: java, jpeg, matlab, libjpeg

SI've got some MATLAB scripts which I successfully compiled into a .jar using the MATLAB builder JA. I've imported this jar to a testing project and it works fine, but when I try to import that .jar file into another project, I get this error:

```
{Warning: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62} 
{??? Error using ==> jpeg_depth
Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62

Error in ==> readjpg at 13



Error in ==> imread at 443
```

The project which launches the error uses swing and awt, the testing project where the .jar works doesn't. So, could this be related ??? I mean, it's like the fact of using awt launches the libjpeg 80, and it seems the .jar has been compiled with the libjpeg60 version.
So, my questions are:
    - Is there any way to forcing MATLAB to use libjpeg80 on compiling?
    - If there isn't, what  should I do?

Thanks in advance.

PS: It seems that the rerror is related with all the functionality that uses libjpeg, because this error is given when the code has a Swing Imagicon, or a BufferedImage, not when this kind of code (image manipulation) isn't. So, the .jar is compiled against the libjpeg.so.62 headers and I need it to compile agains the libjpeg.so.8. I've tried deleting the libjpeg.so.62 and recompiling but that didn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I was using the incorrect JRE. As a default project, Iwas using the system JRE on my project, after change it for the one that comes with MATLAB, the problem dissapeared. Hope this helps someone.